# Retrieve data from device

Tags: javascript, java, python, device, information-retrieval

I'm using a Misfit Beddit device. I would like to retrieve the raw sleep data in .csv format then analyse and plot it using macros.

The parameters needed are skin_temperature, heart rate, gsr, toss_turns and sleep_type (for example, deep, REM and light). The interval for the time ought to be 1 minute for every row. I have retrieved data in various ways using Node.js, Python, JavaScript etc. However, they were not helpful as it was not in the required format.

Here's an example of data from a Basis device:

https://61bdfa02-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/selasubjects/image/Screenshot%202015-09-20%2014.18.18.png?attachauth=ANoY7cqA8bRd6y1ojo1GD1rVsJuxnXa3rqnp_4QdzY-yzLqy-vKQFyA7Q63cyla2vWrm9oEh5ijvwmXCnm2sn_1uDxqFii7iw5-bNvneulyQzbtmsA8sBA_UcAu5HckRRlDJ4Gxwpq8euLfQp_HJGlRXQchNlnsfIwwMeiRrfPcEuR63xFY4e8Ug8sQWgRaUMvm3gs3lwMP_hOb3YkHcZ1AGrb4n7e8qEUWDnI9TgG8BkrZdQsz6OrUdCgl2xAgebPk8r_lN7lKy&attredirects=0

This is how I would need to retrieve data from Beddit sleep device. I know how to auto plot using macros. Any ideas on how to retrieve data from a Beddit device?